# cUrl PHP Get request returning 400 BAD REQUEST but works in Postman

Tags: php, curl

I've got a simple API call that accepts parameters in the url and sends a bearer token over in the header.  I've printer out the url and pasted into Postman with the applied bearer token and it works, but from within PHP I keep getting a 400 Bad Request error.  Here is the code:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    $authorization = 'Authorization: Bearer oireuoijgosrhj9r9regjoregojgjoislgfjs';
    $validate_url = 'https://api.mycustomapi.com/api/envelopes/validate/' . $auth_id .'/' . $content_hash . '/' . $envelope_id;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $validate_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($authorization ));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $json = json_decode($response, true);
    $sigVer = $json['signatureVerified'];
    // Check HTTP status code
    if (!curl_errno($ch)) {
        switch ($http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)) {
            case 200:  # OK
                echo 'response is: ', $sigVer, "\n";
                break;
            case 502:  # server error
                system_message('Received 500 Error from Server');
                break;
            case 400:  # bad request
                echo 'url is: ', $validate_url, "\n";
                system_message('Simple validation must have exactly one content item');
                break;
            default:
                 echo 'Unexpected HTTP code: ', $validate_url, "\n";
        }
    }
    curl_close($ch);
```

In Postman I get my expected response... not sure why cUrl Php is acting differently.

'validate_url' evaluates to:
https://api.myapiservice.com/api/envelopes/validate/auth0|5e17f7e988b0e90e9bdf2e12/6767b1944f523e790c8badf608de140599a424d174a2cad87859a7093aba039f7dc2baaab9f114bf371828364636ec654e1be6aff55e7f65140e24bbbf1a3a7e/140

when using this url in postman I get the following json response:

```
{
    "errorCode": 0,
    "errorMessage": null,
    "envelopeId": 140,
    "blockchainAddress": "0xA300991F77519B5f30552F74779eeEdE398fA59e",
    "clientData": "",
    "signatureVerified": true
}
```

The only setting in postman I'm setting is the Authorization Bearer token which is set to the same bearer token in my cUrl request.  I didn't use my real token or api url in this post however.

If I do a

```
var_dump($response);
die();
```

All I get printed to the screen is

string(800) "
HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request
"

Comment: We don’t know what you are doing in postman and you have not shown us any documentation for that API endpoint either, so we can’t possibly tell if the cURL request you have shown us sends the same/correct data in the same format, or not.

Comment: Start by checking what `$response` actually contains. Right now, you are only looking at the HTTP status code, but there might be an actual error message contained in the response body.

Comment: Understood regarding postman and the api.  Was wondering if there is anything that is fundamentally wrong with my request.  If I take the printout of 'validate_url' that has the values for $auth_id, $content_hash, and $envelope_id inserted, then use that url in postman with the bearer token, I get my expected results.

Comment: So Postman allows you to generate code for your request in Php, so I did that and plugged it into my service and still get a 400 Bad Request.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out what the issue was.  It was simply that one of the vars that I was inserting into my 'validate_url' string was not being urlencoded and since part of that var has a '/' character in it, it was being interpreted as a bad request.